# Spot the mistake: There is only one linear transformation $T$ such that $T:V \rightarrow W$ maps a basis of $n$ elements to $n$ arbitrary elements

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation, fake-proofs

$V$ and $W$ are both linear spaces.

I have a book, Thomas M. Apostol's *Calculus, Volume II* that gives a proof of the statement in the title. However, there is mention of something that I felt was redundant, and I'm not sure if the statement adds anything to the proof. I will give my own proof on here. It is essentially the same as Apostol's proof, but is missing one statement. Is my proof incorrect? If so, what is missing, and why is it important? Be as pedantic as necessary.

We have that $$e_1, e_2, ..., e_n$$ is a basis for the linear space $V$. Thus we know that any $x \in V$ can be written as $$x = \sum_{k=1}^{n} c_ke_k$$
Necessarily, for a linear transformation $T$ to map $e_k$ to an arbitrary element $u_k$, we must have $T(e_k) = u_k$ for $k = 1,2,3...,n$. Let there be a second linear transformation, $T'$, which does the same such that $T'(e_k) = u_k$. This leads us to the following. We can see that, for any x, we have:
$$T(x) = T(\sum_{k=1}^{n} c_ke_k) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} c_kT(e_k) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} c_ku_k = T'(x)$$

Thus $T(x) = T'(x)$ for all $x \in V$. So we must conclude $T = T'$. This concludes the proof.
(The fact that I didn't write down the derivation with $T'$ is not what is missing)

EDIT:
I've received very quick responses. The extra thing was the following sentence:
"If $x = e_k$ for some $k$, then all components of $x$ are $0$ except the $kth$, which is 1, so (2.8) gives $T(e_k) = u_k$, are required."
I'm unsure what talking about the components of $x$ added to the discussion.

Comment: You need to show that there is a linear map $T$ such that $T(e_k)=u_k$ for each $k$.

Comment: so what is the extra thing?

Comment: You haven't explicitly expanded on the fact that $T'$ is linear, while you have expanded $T$ in detail using linearity. There are non-linear maps which take a basis to an arbitrary set, but only one linear map.

Comment: @MarkBennet I wrote that "The fact that I didn't write down the derivation with $T'$ is not what is missing", if that's what you mean.

Comment: @KennyDuran - I was unsure what you meant by that phrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You and other respondents are confused because you haven't quoted Apostol's theorem and proof carefully.

Here is what the theorem actually says. I've bolded the part you bungled.

> Theorem 2.12. Let $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ be a basis for an $n$-dimensional linear space $V$. Let $u_1, \ldots, u_k$ be $n$ arbitrary elements in a linear space $W$. Then **there is one and only one** linear transformation $T:V\to W$ such that $T(e_k)=u_k$ for all $k\in\left\{1, \ldots, n\right\}$. This $T$ maps an arbitrary element $x$ in $V$ as follows: If $x=\sum x_ke_k$, then $T(x)=\sum x_ku_k$.

The sentence following the colon is what Apostol calls (2.8).

Because of the bolded phrase ("one and only one"), a proof of this theorem must show **two** things: (1) such a linear transformation exists, and (2) it is unique. Your proof only shows uniqueness. Apostol's proof shows both existence and uniqueness: the first paragraph shows the former, the second paragraph shows the latter.

Here is the first paragraph, showing existence:

> Every $x$ in $V$ can be expressed uniquely as a linear combination of $e_1, \ldots e_n$, the multipliers $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ being the components of $x$ relative to the ordered basis $(e_1,\ldots, e_n)$. If we define $T$ by (2.8), it is a straightforward matter to verify that $T$ is linear. If $x=e_k$ for some $k$, then all components of $x$ are $0$ except the $k$-th, which is 1, so (2.8) gives $T(e_k)=u_k$, as desired.

What is Apostol doing here? He is proving there does exist a linear transformation $T$ with the property $T(e_k)=u_k$. Which transformation? It's the transformation defined by the formula (2.8). Apostol first checks (or rather, says it is easily checked) that formula (2.8) does indeed define a *linear* transformation. But this alone is not enough: he needs to prove the existence not of *any* old linear transformation, but one for which $T(e_k)=u_k$ for all $k$. The last sentence in the paragraph, the one you ask about, makes this final step explicit.

Comment: I'll acknowledge, though, that this proof could have been written a little more elegantly. The important point is that the condition (2.8) defines the value of a function, $T(x)$, in terms of a particular representation of the input, $x$. It must be checked that (1) this gives a well-defined function (it does because the $e_i$ form a basis, so the representation of $x$ is unique); that (2) the function so defined is in fact linear; and that (3) the function has the desired property, namely it sends $e_k$ to $u_k$.

Comment: Yes! Thanks very much for this reply. I should note that I wasn't meaning to quote Apostol, but to give my own proof which I (incorrectly) interpreted as essentially identical. Once again, thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

You only proved that there is at most one such linear transformation. Where have you really used that the vectors in $V$ form a basis? Your argument, as written, works for any system of generators of $V$.

Comment: I guess that depends on how you interpret "only".

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo It also depends on how one interprets "there is."

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: "If $x=e_k$ for some $k$, then all components of $x$ are $0$ except the $k$th, which is $1$, so (2.8) gives $T(e_k)=u_k$, are required." I'm unsure what talking about the components of $x$ added to the discussion, but this is the missing part. I don't believe Apostol went into detail about the existence of a linear transformation. May I ask how this portion is important to the proof?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo How do you interpret the statement "There is only one car in your garage." ?

Comment: "I've been robbed"

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine, what is supposed to be missing?

Comment: This is a direct quote from the book, and the line that I'm missing. "If $x = e_k$ for some $k$, then all components of $x$ are $0$ except the $kth$, which is 1, so (2.8) gives $T(e_k) = u_k$, are required."

Comment: oh, I think that line can be ommited without much consequence.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/738226)

Answer (score 0):

You have proved that there is *at most* one such linear transformation.  You have not yet proved that such a transformation exists.